# Mongoose: Как дождаться подключения к БД, а потом выполнять следующие действия?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

мне нужно сделать консольное приложение где я должен подключиться к БД, а потом вывести на экран меню для выбора дальнейших действий.

index.js

```
// Set connection from DB
require('./src/services/db')

const messages = require('./src/services/messages')

console.log(messages.start())
```

db.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const { mongodbUri } = require('../config/config')

// log to console
mongoose.set('debug', true)

mongoose.connect(mongodbUri.mlab, { useNewUrlParser: true })

mongoose.connection.on('error', (e) => {
  console.log(`MongoDB connection error: ${e}`)
})
mongoose.connection.once('open', () => console.log('Connected to MongoDB'))
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', () => console.log('Disconnected from MongoDB'))

module.exports = {
  connection: mongoose.connection,
}
```

На выходе я получаю такую картинку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне же нужно что бы лог Connected to MongoDB был до вызова messages.start()

Знаю что нужно использовать await/async но не понимаю как его применить в данном случае.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

index.js

```
// Set connection from DB
const db = require('./src/services/db')

const messages = require('./src/services/messages')

db.connection.on('open', () => console.log(messages.start()))
```